# SFINAE function overload

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I would like to ask about function overloading using SFINAE. I have defined 2 functions, one of which should be used when integral type is passed as parameter, other one should be used when floating point is passed as parameter. Here is code:

```
template <typename T, typename If<IsIntegral<T>::value,T>::Type = 0>
void function(T t) {
    std::cout << "T is integral type" << std::endl;
}
template <typename T, typename If<IsReal<T>::value,T>::Type = 0>
void function(T t) {
    std::cout << "T is real type" << std::endl;
}
```

This compiles fine. When I instantiate integral version of function, like this:

```
function(4);
function(28l);
```

it still works as it should (I get the message "T is integral type"). However, when I add another instance for floating point types:

```
function(4);
function(28l);
function(4.5f);
```

I get error saying, that there is no matching function to call to "function(float)". What is wrong with this snippet of code? By the way, the If template class is only an alias for enable_if.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can't have a constant of type `float` as a template parameter.

Try `class=typename If<IsRead<T>::value,T>::Type` and similar in the other case as a first pass.

If you have C++11, try `using` aliases to get rid of `typename` spam.  In addition, prefer `std::enable_if<?>` to `If<?>` when posting questions asking for help, because I had to **guess** what `If` does (and for all I know, your real problem is in your implementation of `If` and `IsReal` etc).

Comment: Ah thank you so appending '*' to Type in template parameter should solve the problem?

Comment: @AlexanderBily Try it.  Probably will work.  However, there are some quirks in the standard when working with non-type template parameters, I usually find it best to avoid being fancy with them.  The last time it burned me involved something about specialization?  I cannot recall.